# Does MacOS provide a way to see system temperature?

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, mac-mini

I am running Cataline 10.15.7 on a Late 2012 MacMini. Today it black-screened and then hung, requiring a force restart.

I noticed the body of the machine was pretty hot and wondered if this might be a factor. After restarting the fan came on full-blast for a few minutes but hadn't been audible before the crash. I hadn't been using the Mac for anything heavy duty.

Can I easily view temperature and fan status using inbuilt apps? Ideally I'd like to be warned if values indicate a problem since I don't know what values are OK.

I would rather not use command-line, if a visual monitor is provided.

Comment: CPU usage (activity monitor) can often be a good indicator of fan speed and temperature. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103237/how-to-monitor-cpu-core-usage/103249#103249 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/make-activity-monitor-show-more-than-4-cores-worth-of-cpu-usage-in-the-dock

Comment: You can run a cron job with a shell or python script that checks the temperature etc every set interval and notify you via osascript + applescript notification. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel/115373#115373

Comment: @anki I would rather not use cmd line if I don't have to, although thanks for the links :)

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=macos+temperature never saw a native app for that.

Comment: @MrBoy if not command line then look at iStatMenus

Comment: Also when I try that answer, I get `unable to get smc values`

Comment: "I want to do X _without_ using command line" => closed as dupe "how do do X using command line".

Comment: Without the command line and 3rd party tools the answer is simply no.

Comment: "no" is an acceptable answer... :)

Comment: Macs fan control works really well.